# ant clean and ant debug build failed

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

I'm trying to build the jackpal android terminal emulator, but when I try to use the ant clean and ant debug its always says

```
D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:601: Invalid file: C:\Android-Terminal-Emulator-master\libraries\emulatorview\build.xml\
```

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does your build.xml exist? If not, run `android update lib-project` in the root project directory, this will generate a base build.xml for your project. If it does exist, you may need to update your SDK.